# Rpy2 base.as_Date conversion of character dataframe column to date column

Tags: rpy2

I have a rpy2 dataframe mapped with dates as character columns, because I do not want POSIXt/ct columns. I assumed I could then convert that character column to a date and it would take inside the r_df but instead I recieve a float

Setup:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr("base")
```

Short example:

```
> base.as_Date('2020-01-01')
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[18262.000000]

> base.as_Date('2020-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[18262.000000]
```

My actual dataframe:

```
> r_df
R object with classes: ('data.frame',) mapped to:
[IntSexpVe..., IntSexpVe..., IntSexpVe..., FloatSexp..., ..., StrSexpVe..., StrSexpVe..., StrSexpVe..., StrSexpVe...]
....

> r_df[i]
R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
['2016-11-..., '2020-02-..., '2020-07-..., '2019-01-..., ..., '2020-01-..., '2017-01-..., '2020-01-..., '2020-01-...]

> base.as_Date(r_df[i], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[17106.000000, 18293.000000, 18444.000000, 17897.000000, ..., 18262.000000, 17167.000000, 18262.000000, 18262.000000]
```

Another attempt with the same dataframe:

```
> r_df.rx2(col_name)
R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
['2016-11-..., '2020-02-..., '2020-07-..., '2019-01-..., ..., '2020-01-..., '2017-01-..., '2020-01-..., '2020-01-...]

> base.as_Date(r_df.rx2(col_name), '%Y-%m-%d')
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[17106.000000, 18293.000000, 18444.000000, 17897.000000, ..., 18262.000000, 17167.000000, 18262.000000, 18262.000000]
```

Last attempt was trying to convert from POSIXt/ct to Date, thinking maybe it would be able parse more accurately:

```
> r_df.rx2(col_name)
R object with classes: ('POSIXct', 'POSIXt') mapped to:
[2016-11-01, 2020-02-01, ..., 2020-01-01, 2020-01-01, 2017-01-01, 2020-01-01]

> base.as_Date(r_df.rx2(col_name), '%Y-%m-%d')
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[17106.000000, 18293.000000, 18444.000000, 17897.000000, ..., 18262.000000, 17167.000000, 18262.000000, 18262.000000]
```

Executing in r studio and what my expectations are:

```
> as.Date('2020-01-01')
[1] "2020-01-01"
```

This does not seem correct to me. I have used the rpy2 convertor for python pandas df to r dataframe conversion. I am not executing code outside of the default convertor. Any idea how to address this problem and correctly convert the string

Versions:

pandas==1.0.1

rpy2~=3.3.5

R == 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, `Date` objects are (arrays of) floats with a tag to tell R that they are dates.

```
>>> dt = base.as_Date('2020-01-01')
>>> dt                                              
R object with classes: ('Date',) mapped to:
[18262.000000]
```

However, when using R's own print:

```
>>> print(dt)                                       
[1] "2020-01-01"
```

While at R's C-API level this is a float

```
>>> dt.typeof                                                               
<RTYPES.REALSXP: 14>
```

there is an R class attribute that tells R that this is a date.

```
>>> tuple(dt.rclass)                                                        
('Date',)
```